# Asp.NET gives error when I tried to use inner join

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, join, inner-join

```
Baglanti.FnkBaglan();
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
SqlCommand CokSatanlar = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Kitap]  INNER JOIN Yazar ON [Kitap].Yazar_id=[Yazar].YazarID ORDER BY SatisSayisi DESC", Baglanti.baglan);
SqlDataReader DR = CokSatanlar.ExecuteReader();
DT.Load(DR);
RptKitaplariOku.DataSource = DT;
RptKitaplariOku.DataBind();
Baglanti.baglan.Close();

<asp:Table ID="LblYazarAd" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Yazar_isim "+"Yazar_soyisim") %>'></asp:Table>
```

When I tried to use upper code, this code gives following error:

> "An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: DataBinding: 'system.data.datarowview' does
>   not contain a feature called Yazar_isim Yazar_soyisim."

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
<%#Eval("Yazar_isim "+"Yazar_soyisim") %>
```

Should be this:

```
<%#Eval("Yazar_isim") + " " +Eval("Yazar_soyisim") %>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would avoid using "SELECT * FROM" and instead explicitly list the column names.

I expect the error message you are seeing is caused by an expected column name not existing in the database.